# Let $V$ a $F$-vectorial space with finite dimension, $T: V \rightarrow V$ lineal and $W$ invariant under $T$ with dimension $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $V$ a $F$-vectorial space with finite dimension, $T: V \rightarrow V$ lineal and $W$ a proper subspace nonzero of $V$ invariant under $T$ with dimension $n$.Then there exist a basis $\beta$ of $V$ such that:

$[T]_{\beta}=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   A & B \\
   0 & C \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

I tried taking the canonical basis of V and get a transformation with this basis but i´m so confused with this exercise some help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have such abstract looking questions especially in linear algebra, I find it best to look at concrete examples. Say, we have the following matrix-

$$\begin{pmatrix} * & *&0 \\ * & * &0 \\ 0 & 0 &1 \\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\x\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\x\end{pmatrix} $$ So the subspace spanned by $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ is invariant under this transformation. Now you can why the matrix should be of that form. Just a little hint to put things in perspective.

Comment: If you put it that way, that's confusing. The last row needs not be $(0,0,1)$, you could have taken $(\ast, \ast, 1)$. Better still, you could have taken the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \ast & \ast \\ 0 & \ast & \ast \\ 0 &\ast &\ast \end{bmatrix}, $$ which fits more closely with the given exercise.

Comment: I'm still a little confused with exercise and with you answers, what  is *?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro yeah you are right, I just wrote it down quickly.

Comment: @Knight * means any arbitrary element. It could be 1,2,...,etc Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: so i will have a $$[T]_{\beta}=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   A_{n \times n } & B_{n \times (m-n)} \\
   0_{(m-n) \times n} & C_{(m-n) \times (m-n)} \\
  \end{array} } \right]$$ but how can i get this i can verify if i extend a basis of W to a basis of V can you help me

Answer (score 1):

Take a basis of $W$, and then extend it to a basis of the whole space $V$ .

The matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis is of the form $$
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   A & B \\
   0 & C \\
  \end{array} } \right]$$ where $A$ is the matrix of $T$ restricted to $W$ .